# How to reload nginx of remote server using cron as root user

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, cron

I'm using rsync to relay nginx configuration from server A to server B:

```
0,10 * * * * rsync -avz -O --delete /etc/nginx/sites-available -e "ssh -i /home/ubuntu/key.pem" ubuntu@example.com:/etc/nginx
```

Once that is done (every 10 minutes) I need to reload the remote server's configuration. How can I execute `service nginx reload` on the remote server as root?

**UPDATE:**

The reason I need to connect through the `ubuntu` user and then change to root and only then reload is because ngnix fails to reload with any user except root:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2016/06/05 07:18:27 [warn] 15345#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2016/06/05 07:18:27 [emerg] 15345#0: ipv6only is not supported on addr "0.0.0.0:80", ignored in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:4
2016/06/05 07:18:27 [notice] 15345#0: signal process started
2016/06/05 07:18:27 [alert] 15345#0: kill(987, 1) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the command as root by doing:

```
systemctl --host root@example.com reload nginx
```

The example.com host needs to PermitRootLogin
As you don't want to prompt for password you need to create a certificate just like you did rsync and stick it into ./ssh/

Answer (score 1):

Install `sudo` on the remote server (if not already installed). Then configure it to allow `ubuntu` user to execute `service nginx reload` command as `root` without password prompt. Something like the following in `sudoers` file:

```
ubuntu ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service nginx reload
```

And now to reload nginx you just run (from `ubuntu` user):

```
sudo -n service nginx reload
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start your nginx server as `ubuntu` (`ssh -i /home/ubuntu/key.pem" ubuntu@example.com:/etc/nginx`), you don't need to reload as `root`.

You can [send the reload signal](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/) to the current nginx process:

```
ssh -i /home/ubuntu/key.pem" ubuntu@example.com:/etc/nginx -s reload
```

Comment: I want to reload as root because reloading through a different user causes the daemon to fail reloading nginx

Comment: It should not if you call nginx directly instead of using systems or systemctl

Comment: /etc/init.d/nginx reload
 * Reloading nginx configuration nginx                                                                                                                                                       [fail]